# Is it possible to break a DS18B20 temperature probe via a software bug?

Tags: ds18b20

After using the same code for over a year, I made some changes to my code a month ago, and now it appears that one of my DS18B20 temperature probes is broken.

My program reads anywhere from 2 to 4 probes at a given time. I can plug three different probes into my breadboard and see them all in `cat ls /sys/bus/w1/devices/`.

However, after plugging in the malfunctioning probe, it a) never shows up under the previous command; and b) causes the previous command to list any of the other probes.

Would there be anyway to break a DS18B20 temperature probe via software? Perhaps by reading from it too quickly for too long of a time period?

Comment: The short answer is no you can't permanently kill the device via software.  That doesn't mean tho that the device isn't bad for some other reason.  Also you mention breadboard, those connections are very breakable check them twice and/or move new holes never before used etc etc

Answer (score 2):

You can not damage the chip this way unless there were other issues (over voltage, static, etc).

I would try to swap two chips to see for possible connection issue.